# Openshift cron on scaled application

Tags: cron, openshift

I have an openshift application which runs a cron cartridge. I changed it recently to become a scaled app only to realize that the cron will fire on all scaled versions of the app aswell. This messes up my database pretty badly.

Is there any easy way to make the cron tasks only fire once? Tried googling around but found no answer sadly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a somewhat decent answer for this myself and posting it here incase someone else has the same problem. I'm currently using 2 gears for my application so I decided to check the environment variables and decide if the gear is allowed to run the cron job:

```
if(process.env.USER != "XXX"){
    console.log("STOP:"+process.env.USER);
    return;
}
```

This way the cron should only fire on the main gear.

The environment variable can be found by accessing your application with SSH and running the env command at the shell prompt.